# How can I import local package in another npm package and test it with Typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, npm, webpack

Given 3 npm projects with Webpack and Typescript.

```
├── project1/
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src/
│   │     └── index.ts
│   └── webpack1.config.js
├── project2
    ├── index.ts
    ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── webpack2.config.js
└── project3/
    └── index.html
```

How can import `Project1` into `Project2` and then use `Project2` in src html tag? 
I tried it in a thousand different ways (npm link) and there is no way to be able to do some tests with the module Project 2. Always I have problems with module not found in `Project2`.

Here my configs:
**PROJECT1**

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.13.6",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'COMMON1',
  },
};
-------------------------------------------------src/index.ts
export class Test1{
    public Init(){
        console.log("Hello World!!");
    }
}
```

**PROJECT2**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: 'index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    library: 'common2',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
----------------------------tsconfig.json
{
  "name": "project2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
---------------------------------------------------------
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "incremental": true,                
    "target": "es5",                         
    "module": "CommonJS",                    
    "outDir": "./dist/",                        
    "strict": true,                           
    "baseUrl": "./",                       
    "paths": {
      "project1": [ "../project1/src" ],
      "project1/*": [ "../project1/src/*" ]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  
  }
}
-------------------------------------------------index.ts


 import { Test1} from "project1";  //Alwayas error!!

   new Test1().Init();
   const test1= 1;
   export { test1, Test1};
```

**PROJECT3**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="../project2/dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script>// I need common2.test1</script>
...
```

Basically how can I get `common2.test1` in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `package.json` in **PROJECT1** says your main files are in `dist/bundle.js`, before doing `npm link` in the source **PROJECT1** and then doing `npm link project1` in the destination **PROJECT2**, you need to **bundle PROJECT1** so the `dist/` folder is populated.

TSC compiler will say the `module is not found` due to the fact that `dist/` folder doesnt exist at all.

Comment: If I'm don't wrong, there are others alteratives instead of put dist/bundle.js in the main? Or there are other better solution?

Comment: Sure there are, you can just dont put any "main" param at all, or user any other folder/name combination, it depends in how you tsconfig.json file is done, where are you willing to put your compiled files etc